# When prime element in an integral domain stays prime in integral extension

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, integral-extensions

All rings below are assumed to be commutative with unity.

Let $A\subseteq B$ be an integral extension of integral domains ($A,B$ are both integral domains and $B$ integral over $A$). If $p\in A$ is a prime element in $A$ then is $p$ a prime element in $B$ also ? If this is not true in general, what if we take $B$ to be the normalization of $A$ (integral closure of $A$ in its fraction field), is the result true then ?

Comment: An answer to your second question can be found in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291579/when-does-prime-elements-remain-prime-in-certain-integral-extension

Answer (score 3):

In general prime elements do not remain prime in integral extensions.
For example in the situation $A=\mathbb Z\subset B=\mathbb Z[i]$, the prime $2\in A$ does not remain prime in $B$ since $2$ divides $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ without dividing any of its two factors $1\pm i$.

Comment: Thanks, really simple example. Please give the normalization question some thought if possible