# When every prime/irreducible element remains prime/irreducible in a ring extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

Let $A \subseteq B$ be two commutative integral domains which are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

> **Question 1:** Is it possible to find mild conditions on $A, B, A \subseteq B$ such that the following property P is satisfied:
>
> **Property P:** Every prime element in $A$ remains prime in $B$.

**An empty example:** $A=\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$, $B=\mathbb{C}[x]$. There are no prime elements in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$, so the property is satisfied.
See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276356/a-simple-algebraic-ring-extension-of-a-ufd-having-no-prime-elements/2276385#comment4682608_2276385) question.

**A nice example:** If $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in the fraction field of $A$, then the property is satisfied, as was proved in an answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291579/when-does-prime-elements-remain-prime-in-certain-integral-extension) MO question.

**Non-examples:** 
**(i)** $A=\mathbb{C}[x^2]$, $B=\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$.
$x^2$ is prime (= irreducible in a UFD) in $\mathbb{C}[x^2]$, but $x^2$ is not prime in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ (it remains irreducible), since $x^2$ divides $x^6=x^2x^2x^2=x^3x^3$ but it does not divide $x^3$.
**(ii)** $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}[i]$. $2$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ (= irreducible in a UFD), but $2$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (also, it is not irreducible), since $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ divides the product $(1+i)(1-i)$ but it does not divide $1+i$ or $1-i$; this example was presented in an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621990/when-prime-element-in-an-integral-domain-stays-prime-in-integral-extension) question.

**A plausible answer 1?** Four mild conditions:
**(i)** $Q(A)=Q(B)$. ($Q(D)$ denotes the fraction field of an integral domain $D$).
**(ii)** $A^{\times}=B^{\times}$.  ($S^{\times}$ denotes the invertible elements of a set $S$).
**(iii)** $B$ is integral over $A$. **(iv)** $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra.

---

> **Question 2:** Is it possible to find mild conditions on $A, B, A \subseteq B$ such that the following property I is satisfied:
>
> **Property I:** Every irreducible element in $A$ remains irreducible in $B$.

Notice that the first, empty example, is not valid anymore since $x^2,x^3$ are irreducibles in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$, but reducibles in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Now I have asked the above question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353057/prime-elements-in-certain-integral-ring-extensions) also.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems like in your examples, $A$ and $B$ have the same field of fractions, whereas, in your non-examples, they do not. When $A$ is a UFD, the condition may have some connection with the condition of being etale in codimension.

Comment: @Youngsu, thank you for your observation. Further elaboration is welcome (as an answer, if you like).

Comment: @Youngsu, if I am not wrong, perhaps the following paper is relevant (at least in special cases of $A,B$): H. Bass, Differential structure of etale extensions of polynomial algebras, in Commutative Algebra, M. Hochster, C. Huncke and J. D. Sally (ed.), Springer-Verlag, New York, 1989, Proceedings of a Microprogram Held, June 15-July 2, 1987.

Comment: I was not aware of that paper, and I will take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: Another paper for special cases $A,B$ is: K. Adjamagbo, On separable algebras over a UFD and the Jacobian Conjecture in any characteristic, in Automorphisms of affine spaces, A. van den Essen (ed.), Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1995, Proceedings of a Conference held in Curacao (Netherlands Antilles), July 4-8, 1994, under the auspices of the Caribbean mathematics Foundation (CMF).

Comment: @Youngsu, please, could you further explain your idea? You require that $A$ is a UFD, $Q(A)=Q(B)$ and? Is it necessary that $A$ is a UFD?

Comment: Hi. It is related to reducedness. Suppose that if $p$ factors as $p = q^s$ in $B$, then $A_p \subset B_q$ is not unramified, thus not etale. Also, look at the Hurwitz formula.

Comment: @Youngsu, thank you for your explanation! I will think about your ideas. (Probably in a few days I will again ask you about your ideas..).

Comment: @Youngsu, please could you write the specific result you have in mind? What if we further assume that every irreducible element of $A$ is square-free in $B$?

Comment: @Youngsu, is it necessary that $A$ is a UFD and/or $Q(A)=A(B)$? Thank you.

Comment: I do not think an etale map requires the source to be a UFD or the map is birational.

Comment: @Youngsu, thank you. Please: (1) What did you mean in your first comment? (2) Did you claim the following: If $A \subseteq B$ is etale, then every prime element in $A$ remains prime in $B$?

Comment: Your "four" mild conditions are three in number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you for reading carefully my question. I will now either change to "three" or mention the fourth condition which appeared in a previous version to my above question. Please, do you have any ideas concerning my question?

Comment: Sorry, everything I thought of has already been suggested here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, please could you elaborate on the ideas presented by Youngsu? I do not understand what exactly was suggested.

Comment: Sorry, anything with the word "etale" in it is above my pay grade.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you for trying to help. You surely know more than I about etale extensions, but as you wish. (Please, at least what are the exact claims involving etaleness that are relevant here?).

Comment: "You surely know more than I about etale extensions" only in the sense that zero is twice zero. Honestly, this is not false modesty on my part. I truly have much to be modest about.

Comment: :-) ok. Thank you. (Any comments to this or other questions of mine are welcome).