# Example of $A \subseteq B$, $Q(A)=Q(B)$, with $a \in A$ prime in $A$ but not prime in $B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A \subseteq B$ be two $k$-algebras which are (commutative) integral domains.
Assume that $A,B$ have the same field of fractions, $Q(A)=A(B)$.

> Is it possible that there exists a prime element in $A$ which is not a prime element in $B$?

In other words, is there $a \in A$ such that $A/aA$ is an integral domain, but $B/aB$ is not an intrgral domain?

**Remarks:**
Consider $A=k[x^2,x^3]$, $B=k[x]$.

**(1)** It is not an example, since there are no prime elements in $A$.

**(2)** Irreducibles in $A$ do not remain irreducibles (= prime, since $B$ is a UFD) in $B$; indeed, $x^2$ is irreducible in $A$, but reducible in $B$.

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548524/when-every-prime-element-remains-prime-in-a-ring-extension) similar but not identical question.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

---

After the discussion in the comments, I wish to further assume that:

**(i)** $A^{\times}=B^{\times}=k^{\times}$.  ($S^{\times}$ denotes the invertible elements in a set $S$).

**(ii)** $B$ is integral over $A$.

> Is it true that every prime element in $A$ remains prime in $B$?

Observe that $A=\mathbb{Z}, B=\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not a counterexample, since $Q(A)=\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(i)= Q(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $B$ the fraction field of $A$.

Comment: Oh, nice, I like that idea. So what if we further assume some finiteness conditions on the extension? For example, $B$ is a finitely generated algebra over $A$?

Comment: The same idea works. Take $A$ to be the integers, and $B$ its localization at the multiplicative set {$1,f,f^2,...$}, son some nonzero element $f$.

Comment: Thank you! So what if we further require that $A^{\times}=B^{\times}=k$ (the invertible elements in $A$ equal the invertible elements in $B$ and equal $k$)?

Comment: What about $k[x,xy]\subset k[x,y]$?

Comment: Nice. $xy$ is prime in $k[x,xy]$, but it is not prime in $k[x,y]$ (since it is reducible in $k[x,y]$). Please do you think that there exists a mild condition that guarantees that each prime $a \in A$ remains prime in $B$? Perhaps flatness? $B$ is an integral extension? This does not contradict https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621990/when-prime-element-in-an-integral-domain-stays-prime-in-integral-extension?rq=1.

Comment: $k[x,xy] \subset k[x,y]$ is not flat, right?